# How to make Bootstrap 4 Image Overlay card entirely clickable?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using the Bootstrap 4 card element to create an image grid, with headings overlaid onto each one, but can only seem to link up the text, not the image itself.

I've tried using the stretched link method and it doesn't seem to work. I've also tried putting the whole card in an anchor tag and that also doesn't seem to work - where am I going wrong?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="card text-white col-md-4 p-3 border-0">
    <img alt="Card image" class="card-img" src="..." />
      <div class="card-img-overlay">
        <a href="..." class="stretched-link">
          <h2 class="card-title">Title here</h2>
        </a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would have thought the link would stretch to the whole card as i've seen on the Bootstrap website, but it just doesn't - any help would greatly be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work fine when you put the `card` inside the column...

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="text-white col-md-4 p-3 border-0">
        <div class="card">
            <img alt="Card image" class="card-img" src="..." />
            <div class="card-img-overlay">
                <a href="#" class="stretched-link" id="cardlink">
                    <h2 class="card-title">Title here</h2>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/p/8r7GoatHj1

Comment: I see it works in your codeply - but i've tried the exact same code on our website and it's still not working. I'm guessing this is something to do with something conflicting in the websites CSS file?

Answer (score -1):

It's working well what's the problem? maybe it's being effected by the another elements in your document?

try this in new file called test.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>



<div class="row">
  <div class="card text-white col-md-4 p-3 border-0">
    <img alt="Card image" class="card-img" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
      <div class="card-img-overlay">
        <a href="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="stretched-link">
          <h2 class="card-title">Title here</h2>
        </a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```